# Host with self-signed certificate as a target of Google Cloud Tasks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I use Google Cloud Tasks to call https endpoint - host has self-signed certificate installed. It doesn't need to have domain, so the communication is just by IP address.

However, Google Cloud Tasks doesn't work with that certificate. Do you have any idea how to bypass it? Is there any way to skip SSL errors?

Unfortunately I can't a free Let's Encrypt certificate since it requires a domain, which for some reason I don't want to use.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to disable certificate validation for Cloud Tasks. Can you use an HTTP endpoint instead?